# Print title on every page based on a column value - Datatables

Tags: printing, html-table, jquery-plugins, datatables

Is there any way to break page after a certain column value finished and make that value print title?

Datatables print a title only in first page but I have to add title in every page. In every office location there is many user and I have to add a custom title each page based on ''Office" location, and add a page break when all users of a office location is printed and then print new office's user to a separate page and add 'Office' name as custom title.

A scenario is , I have 500 row where only 5 office location used like 'New York', 'California', 'Washington' etc. I want to print all the row at once but when all the data of a location is printed say 200 data of 'New york' is printed I want a ""Page-Break" and make only those pages title 'New-York', when 'California's' data is printing made title 'California' dynamically and after all row's of 'California' printed add a page-break and so on.

I badly need this solution, If possible please help me. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        order: [[2, "asc"]],
        buttons: [
            'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Sample fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/eLLc2hoc/2/